# How to access perforce of remote host with command line

Tags: version-control, command-line, command, perforce

I am trying to access perforce sitting on remote machine(I know its IP and port) using command line. I know p4v command is used to run perforce but it runs perforce GUI and not command line.

Why I want this because I want to run some commands(similar to sync) on remote host perforce. These command provides so many features which I can get in GUI.

I heard some p4 settings had to be done for this. I tried [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html#1070447) link also but doesn't seem to work.

Can any one tell me how to access perforce for command line. I am looking for some step by step solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible, i.e., you cannot run p4 client commands on a remote machine.

If you are using Windows, then try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062).

`psexec \\REMOTE_MACHINE p4.exe [g-opts] sync \\depot\path\...`

Set the [global options [g-opts]](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.gopts.html#1040647) to override the remote machine environment, e.g. client, p4 server, port etc.

HTH,